# jshint and sublimelinter settings config on mac

Tags: sublimetext3, jshint, sublimelinter

I'm trying to configure sublimelinter, specifically jshint on my Mac. On my windows version of SublimeText there is the following section in `SublimeLinter.sublime-settings`

```
 "jshint_options":
    {
        // To fix column positions for JSHint errors you may want to add `"indent": 1` to your
        // **User** "jshint_options". This issue affects users with tabs for indentation.
        // This fix was reverted due to a conflict with using the `"white": true` option.
        // "indent": 1,
        "evil": true,
        "regexdash": true,
        "browser": true,
        "wsh": true,
        "trailing": true,
        "sub": true
    },
```

When I view the file on my Mac this section doesn't exist, is there a place to edit these option on the Mac version without a separate settings file? Or a global settings file for jshint?

I've been digging through similar questions but haven't found a clear solution.

**Update:**

Actually it doesn't seem to catch any errors at all when using it on the console. My javascript file doesn't end in `.js` how can I configure it to look at different extensions? I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: I didn't use sublimelinter yet, but are you sure you are working on same sublimelinter version on both machines? Documentation says that linters are separated now, and probably their options are separated as well. Did you check [sublimelinter-jshint docs](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-jshint)

Comment: yep it looks like the windows version is the older version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general I would recommend against configuring JSHint system-wide. It's usually safer to create a `.jshintrc` file for each project your work on because it's likely they will have different JSHint requirements.

The `jshint_options` SublimeLinter setting you mention in your question is from the old version of SublimeLinter, which has recently been reworked to have a simple plugin architecture. The JSHint plugin (which I assume you are using, since the settings you tried didn't work) makes the [same recommendation](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-jshint#settings):

> You can configure `jshint` options in the way you would from the command line, with `.jshintrc` files.

The added benefit of this approach is that you can commit the `.jshintrc` file to your repository and ensure that anyone who works on the project is working with the same JSHint rules, rather than their own system-wide settings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I do realize this is best practice but unfortunately with this work (salesforce) I can't use grunt or anything so I'd be a very manual process. I updated my question with my results based on trying to set it globally.

Answer (score 12):

There's another way to set options **globally**, without using ".jshintrc" files.
1) create a file with any name (e.g. "jshint.conf"). my file is:

```
{
  "globals": { "$": false },
  "globalstrict": true,
  "devel": true
}
```

2) put it anywhere. in my case it is: "c:\Users\Smith\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\"

3) make the next reference in section "jshint"->"args" of sublime-linter user setting (user/SublimeLinter.sublime-settings):

```
{
    "user": {
        "linters": {
            "jshint": {
                "args": [
                    "--config", "c:\\Users\\Smith\\AppData\\Roaming\\Sublime Text 3\\Packages\\User\\jshint.conf"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4) Enjoy!