# How do I modify jshint sublimelinter settings?

Tags: sublimetext3, jshint, sublimelinter

I am sorrry if this is a duplicate question.

I want to turn off warnings for semi-colon, and change appearance of warning cursors in jshint sublimelinter.

What file or menu do I need to access to change these settings?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194603/jshint-and-sublimelinter-settings-config-on-mac) duplicate answer, among the many questions.

Create a .jshintrc file in the directory you want to lint (a simple JSON file like [this](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-jshint/blob/master/.jshintrc), and drop your options in there. You'll be looking for the asi option for semicolons. To set it globally you can place it in a top-level folder. You can also specify a path in `Preferences: SublimeLinter Settings` from the Command Palette:

```
            "args": [
                "--config",
                "path/to/my/file/.jshintrc"
            ],
```

This seems to override a nearby .jshintrc file in my case, which may not be what you want.

Apparently in Sublime Text 2 it was possible to change these in the SublimeLinter settings using a "jshint_options" setting, but this is apparently no longer possible (see [issue #3](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-jshint/issues/3)).